# Member variable in C++ class that is always constant for all objects of that class?

Tags: c++

I'm constructing a class where I have three member variables that I want to always be the same value NO MATTER WHAT.

I have

```
class foo{

public:
    double var_1, var_2, var_3;
    double x=1, y=2, z=3;

[functions go here]

};
```

that gave me an error since I can't initialize a variable like that. But I want x, y and z to always be 1, 2 and 3 respectively. I tried defining them outside the class but that doesn't work since I want them to be member variables of the class.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do all objects of type `foo` use the same `const` values? `x=1` `y=2` `z=3`

Comment: Can you use specific C++11 features? (be caution: if your code uses a C++11 feature, then your code may not compile on many current C++ compilers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make these values static for the class, this way all object will inherit these same values.

```
static const int x = 1;
static const int y = 2;
static const int z = 3;
```

through technically, this does not define the variable. If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, you may specify a constant initializer in the static data member's declaration. This constant initializer must be an integral constant expression. Note that the constant initializer is not a definition. You still need to define the static member in an enclosing namespace.

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <//libs....>
int foo::x;
int foo::y;
int foo::z;
//class functions down below
```

Comment: `static const` or `static constexpr` is better.

Comment: he never specified if he wanted the values to remain constant, he might wish to modify the values at a later point in the program.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `static const int` can be initialized in the class declaration.

Comment: @Need4Sleep: "[...] that I want to always be the same value NO MATTER WHAT."

Comment: the title specify he wants it constant

Comment: @Karolis it's not technically a definition(you still must define the variable outside of the class)

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė http://ideone.com/i7lUjS or compile your original example with all optimisations disabled.

Comment: @Flexo, that does make sense. Still, the answer should indicate that the explicit definition is only needed in some cases.

Comment: @Karolis: It's always "needed" for a compliant program. Just if you get "lucky" and all references to the variable are inlined then you won't see any link failures from failing to include it. As Flexo has already suggested.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, looking at the standard (a draft) I see (9.4.2-3) *"<...>The [static] member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used <...>"*. Also, (3.2-2) *"<...> [a thing] is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression <...>"*. From which I deduce that a constant does not need to be defined.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: A reasonable deduction. Well found.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an initializer list in the constructor to set these fields' initial values, just as with any other member:

```
class foo {
public:
    const double x;
    const double y;
    const double z;

    foo() : x(1), y(2), z(3) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Initialization list is a very nice way of doing this: the values of x y and z will always be 1, 2 and 3 respectively every time you instantiated your class into an object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to make them static. You could declare them like this:

```
class foo{

public:
    double var_1, var_2, var_3;
    const double x=1.0;
    const double y=2.0;
    const double z=3.0;

[functions go here]

};
```

Though if they are integer values then declaring them as `int`s would be better.

Comment: That's a C++11 feature for non-int types

Comment: Actually, I'm going to downvote this for the time being since OP clearly is not using C++11 and so this won't work.

Comment: @Pubby: What makes you so sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Since OP posted almost identical code. The only difference is that OP's is all on one line. (This answer's original explanation was that he could not initialize multiple variables on one line which was incorrect)